# Segmentation fault during installation of Python 3.6 on Debian 8

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install Python 3.6 on Debain 8. When I run the `make` command, an error occurs.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release:    8.11
Codename:   jessie
```

The commands I run:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tgz
tar xvf Python-3.6.3.tgz
cd Python-3.6.3
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j8  # Error occurs here
sudo make altinstall
python3.6
```

That's the error

```
...
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma              
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

The following modules found by detect_modules() in setup.py, have been
built by the Makefile instead, as configured by the Setup files:
atexit                pwd                   time               
running build_scripts
copying and adjusting /home/lucas/Python-3.6.3/Tools/scripts/pydoc3 -> build/scripts-3.6
copying and adjusting /home/lucas/Python-3.6.3/Tools/scripts/idle3 -> build/scripts-3.6
copying and adjusting /home/lucas/Python-3.6.3/Tools/scripts/2to3 -> build/scripts-3.6
copying and adjusting /home/lucas/Python-3.6.3/Tools/scripts/pyvenv -> build/scripts-3.6
changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/pydoc3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/idle3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/2to3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/pyvenv from 644 to 755
renaming build/scripts-3.6/pydoc3 to build/scripts-3.6/pydoc3.6
renaming build/scripts-3.6/idle3 to build/scripts-3.6/idle3.6
renaming build/scripts-3.6/2to3 to build/scripts-3.6/2to3-3.6
renaming build/scripts-3.6/pyvenv to build/scripts-3.6/pyvenv-3.6
Segmentation fault


Makefile:586: recipe for target 'sharedmods' failed
make[2]: *** [sharedmods] Error 139
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/lucas/Python-3.6.3'
Makefile:479: recipe for target 'build_all_generate_profile' failed
make[1]: *** [build_all_generate_profile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lucas/Python-3.6.3'
Makefile:460: recipe for target 'profile-opt' failed
make: *** [profile-opt] Error 2
```

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 18.04 and doing the same thing but for python3.7.0 and have been able to narrow the missing optional modules down to just _dbm but now I'm stumpped, as I'm not sure what library dependency is required for it.
for the other two I installed liblzma-dev and libgdbm-dev

Comment: The missing modules aren't the problem - those messages are warnings, not errors.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279671/compile-python-3-6-2-on-debian-jessie-segfaults-on-sharedmods) suggests the issue might be architecture/compiler related.  A deleted answer to the same question suggests compiling _without_ `--enable-optimizations`.  Make sure to run `make clean` before rebuilding.

Answer (score 4):

#### Warning:

If you try this because of a failed installation, delete as much as you can of the failed install because it is not a good idea to leave broken installs on your computer (it tends to break re-installs)
try:

```
rm -rfv <broken_python_version>
locate <broken_python_version>
rm -rfv `locate <broken_python_install>`
```

#### Instructions

Try installing these modules with `apt` first by using

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev wget libbz2-dev tk-dev liblzma-dev lzma
```

Then download python using wget:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tgz
```

or just download the latest version from the [python official website](https://python.org/downloads/). To build python, enter:

```
tar -xf Python-3.6.3.tgz && rm Python-3.6.3.tgz # or your python version
cd Python-3.6.3 # or your python version
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j `nproc` # optimized for the number of processors on your computer
sudo make altinstall
```

To test if the python installation works try:

```
python3 --version # python3 can be replaced with python3.8 depending on your python version
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [a solution from pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1889#issuecomment-833587851).

I applies this to Ubuntu 22.04, via `asdf`/`pyenv`.

```bash
sudo apt install clang -y
CC=clang asdf install python 3.6.15
```

There is [another solution](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1889#issuecomment-837697366) from the same thread with extra work on patching build file. I didn't test it yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt install python3-gdbm=3.5.1-1 #resolve _gdbm
sudo apt install libgdbm-compat-dev   #resolve _dbm
sudo apt install liblzma-dev          #resolvde _lzma
```